# XPath expression: selecting text nodes between element nodes

Tags: xpath, textnode

Based in the following HTML I want to extract TextA, TextC and TextE.

```
<div id='content'>
    TextA
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p>TextB</p>
    TextC
    <br/>
    TextC
    <p>TextD</p>
    TextE
</div>
```

I tried to get TextC like so but I don't get the result I want:

- Query: 
  `//*[preceding::p[contains(.,"TextB")] and following::p[contains(.,"TextD")]]`
- Expected result: 
  `["TextC", <br/>, "TextC"]`
- Actual result: 
  `[<br/>]`

Is there a way to select the text nodes without using indexes like `//div/text()[1]`?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. In the first line you say "I want to extract TextA, TextC, and TextE" but then later you talk about wanting to select `["TextC", <br/>, "TextC"]`. Please clearly explain what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Got it. I do want to extract all of the said text nodes, my query was just an example of how I tried to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the two text nodes aren't in the result of your XPath is because `*` only match *elements*. To match both element and text node you can use `node()` instead :

```
//node()[preceding::p[contains(.,"TextB")] and following::p[contains(.,"TextD")]]
```

**<kbd>[Demo](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/dNhP5UvnF)</kbd>**

Or if you want to get the text nodes only i.e excluding `<br/>`, you can use `text()` instead of `node()`:

```
//text()[preceding::p[contains(.,"TextB")] and following::p[contains(.,"TextD")]]
```

Comment: Fixed a copy-paste mistake in the code. +1. BTW @OP you may get better efficiency if you use `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` instead of `preceding` and `following`, assuming that you can be sure the `<p>` elements you're referring to are on the same level as the text node. You may even want `preceding-sibling::p[1]`, for greater specificity and efficiency, depending on how broadly you're going to apply this technique to different XML inputs.

Comment: That's just what I've been looking for. Thanks!